# Is an OpenVPN client able to read the OpenVPN server configuration

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I have access to my companies OpenVPN Server to access some documents from home and want to see what settings are configured on the Server.

We use the open-source community version OpenVPN, can I somehow read the whole server configuration? I am not interested in any paths to certificates, just the configured settings.

I understand that the negotiated encryption/hashing algorithms reflect some of the server configuration but not all of it.

Comment: Wouldn't that be a possible security issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Your client only knows the current algorithm in use, compression settings and arguments the server is set to "Push" such as default gateway.

Comment: Once connected to the server, if your network administrator allows you to access to the server config file, you **can** read and even write it.  But that would be very insecure server.

Comment: @dotvotdot and quite unlikely as its common to install OpenVPN in system directories not /users on win or /home on linux.

Comment: @Linef4uit yes .. but the OpenVPN server config file can be read over a VPN provided the underlying security allows it.